# Using AutoFac with ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: c#, autofac

I read the official documents, for example as follows:

```
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

        public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
        {
            get { return _containerProvider; }
        }

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().HttpRequestScoped();

            _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
        }
```

This is what I do in accordance with the official examples, but the problem is the method HttpRequestScoped does not exist, why is this?

Also, I would like to ask how to obtain an instance of the interface and the Singleton Pattern in the page.

Comment: Have you read http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration#Implement_IContainerProviderAccessor_in_Global.asax ? Quote from the Component Lifetime section: *You can register components using the "HttpRequestScoped()" extension method in the Autofac.Integration.Web namespace*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `using AutoFac.Integration.Web;`.

Comment: Only Autofac.Integration.Web no Autofac.Web

Comment: And that requires the Http Modules and the implemented interface on Global.

Comment: HttpRequestScoped "Why did not this method

Answer (score 0):

I think that HttpRequestScoped is no longer used. Try using InstancePerHttpRequest() instead.